# Play Animated Loader in Small part of the page not through the entire page in React native

Tags: react-native

I have a page where there is two part one header part and below it there is top tab bar, when changes the tab there is loading different data and shows a loader, but the loader overlays throughout the whole page, but i only want to play the loader on the tab page not on the header page, i used animated loader in that tab page,

````
                visible={loaderVisible}
                overlayColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.75)"
                source={require("../assets/loader_load.json")}
                animationStyle={{width:100,height:100}}
                speed={1}
            >
                <Text>Please Wait...</Text>
            </AnimatedLoader>```
please help what to do ...to play the loader within the tab page
````

Answer (score 0):

To show to modal inside Top Tab you should need to call it inside the tab screens not at the root of the tab Compoennt, if you do this loader will run on top of tabs, so use inside that will work inside screen only

if you want to use it root where Tabs reside then put AnimatedLoader in modal view and set styling like position : 'ablsolute' and make it align center

if get stuck you should just give color to check how much area is take-over by Loader modal this will help you to align properly

Comment: i call it from tab component but it overlays throught page not understand what to do for overalying color only taken palce for the tab component